# After doing FormsAuthentication.SignOut(), user is not able to login again

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using formAuthentication with the following Web.Config file.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="SnowBall" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" loginUrl="Login.aspx"      cookieless="AutoDetect">
    </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I have a user control which has a LogOut button. Code of the logout button is:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

After executing this code, I am no longer able to authenticate the user. When i click "Sign In", the page is refreshed and event handlers are not executed.

When I close the browser window and re-run the site, everything works fine. Please help me.

Comment: May be stupid questions: 
- Do client's clock correct?
- Have you some cache setting for page where user redirected after login?

Comment: nopes,no cache settings.

Comment: Using Fiddler check auth cookies after second login, If it present, then everything ok. Otherwise you have some problems in server code.

Comment: I am creating a website which is running on the file system.It opens up in IE.But fiddler is not able to show any info.

Comment: My project has the same environment :) , just check you've specified correct listen port for Fiddler.

Comment: I am new to fiddler.Please guide me regarding this.

Comment: Try ending the session when logging out a user.

Comment: not using session.Have tried setting httpContext.current.user=null but its still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.Hope it helps somebody out there

Problem lies with this line

```
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

What it does is redirects user to Login.aspx with ReturnUrl as querystring.For Eg.

Login.aspx?ReturnUrl="Name of the page from where logout happened";

Now what happened was that FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl() preserved this querystring path and after authentication was redirecting to this path.the user credentials i was putting in were not authorized to view this page.So i was always on the login screen.

To Resolve this issue replace

```
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

With

```
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
```

Comment: FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage() is neater. You should have a defaultUrl attribute set in your Web.config, ie  

<forms loginUrl="login.aspx"
    defaultUrl="index.aspx" />

Comment: No i donot have defaultUrl set there. I was facing same issue with FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage().

Answer (score 0):

First you need to clear that there are two separate Ids one is session id which is alloted for browser session and another is form authentication cookie which is encrypted alphanumeric id.

Whenever you use formauthentication.signout your formauthentication cookies will removed as per your implementation.But your session id will remain there.

You cancheck it by using fiddler/ firefox browser.